SQL exercise: why does the solution require using JOIN to solve the question, and why can't COUNT(complaintid) be used instead of COUNT(fineid)?
I'm doing this exercise which I found on a website where 2 tables are given:
TBL #1 - Fines:
fineID, fineDate, empID, amount
  10001 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000           1   250.00
  10002 2017-03-11 00:00:00.000           2   250.00
  10003 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000           4   500.00
  10004 2017-07-23 00:00:00.000           4   250.00
  10005 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000           2   500.00
  10006 2017-11-02 00:00:00.000           2   750.00
  10007 2017-11-30 00:00:00.000           3  1000.00
  10008 2017-12-03 00:00:00.000           1   250.00
                                                                                                                                                                                          

TBL #2 - Complaints:
Columns: complaintId, compDate, fineId, description
   1011 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000       10003 ##$&&!                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   1012 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000       10004 %$#&*&$#!                                                                                                                                                                                               
   1013 2017-03-02 00:00:00.000       10001 $#^*&#!                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   1014 2017-11-10 00:00:00.000       10006 &$!                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   1015 2017-12-04 00:00:00.000       10007 *&%()#!                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   1016 2017-12-08 00:00:00.000       10007 8&(^$%$! 

I am asked to retrieve the fine which had received the most complaints.
The solution provided for this exercise is the following query:
SELECT TOP 1 f.fineId, COUNT(c.fineId) comp_count
FROM fines f
JOIN complaints c
ON f.fineId = c.fineId
GROUP BY f.fineId
ORDER BY comp_count DESC;

the output is this:



fineId
comp_count




10001
2



My initial query is the one below, and it returns the same output as shown above:
SELECT TOP 1 fineId, COUNT(complaintId) comp_count
FROM complaints 
GROUP BY fineId
ORDER BY comp_count DESC;

I'm learning SQL and want to understand the rationale behind things. Why did they have to use the fines table, and why did they count the fineId? Is it necessary, and if so, why? I suspect that solution #1 has some sort of purpose; I just don't understand it.
I'd appreciate your help, thanks!

The answer to your question would depend on the actual data and the intention.  BTW...neither MySQL nor Postgres supports TOP syntax.  But SQL Server does, which is probably your actual database.

Who's THEY? I don't see a reason for invoking fines either.

The only reason to use the JOIN would be to eliminate fines not associated with a complaint. But, the TOP 1 effectively does that anyway (because the top 1, by definition, must be a fine associated to a complaint). As for what to count, it really doesn't matter with that data; COUNT() ignores/skips NULL values, but neither version has any nulls, so both queries have COUNT(*) == COUNT(fineid) == COUNT(complaintid). Note, you can any column because you're not using COUNT(DISTINCT <column>)

If you needed any other information from the fines table, such as the date, amount, or offence information, the join would be required. The only other reason for the join would be to guarantee that a matching fines row exists.  However, if the first query referenced and grouped by c.fineId instead of f.fineId and a foreign key were defined between the two tables, the presence of the fines row is already guaranteed, and the execution plan would actually ignore that table reference.  See this db<>fiddle.

@MattBailie - thank you! I was actually wondering about how to deal with COUNT and nulls..

@TN - thank you so much for your help, that cleared up some things for me :)

It just occurred to me that there is one degenerate edge case: If there are no complaints at all, you would need a LEFT JOIN between fines and complaints to get a result. That result would be the fineId of some arbitrary fine row, because they all have a complaint count of zero.  Also, COUNT(c.fineId) would need to be used so that you do not count unmatched left-join cases. COUNT(f.fineId) and COUNT(*) would both yield a count of 1 for an unmatched left-join. However, if the requirements are amended to request "most complaints, having at least one", the original logic stands.

well, i think the purpose on this is to teach you how to make Join between 2 tables.
Why using COUNT(c.fineId):

just a way to count how many times the fineID appears on the complaints
table.
the way you did is a simplest way to get the same result, but let suppose
that instead showing the FineId you need to show the EmpId, you would need
to make the join between the 2 tables to get both fields.

